# Понятно ли подобное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Смотрел сегодня новости по российскому "Первому каналу" и одна длинная фраза показалось мне что-то уж очень тяжеловесной. Во всяком случае лично я как-то сразу и не понял :-). Хочу спросить у участников форума, а как вам, понятно ли подобное предложение? Или это только моё такое *субъективное* восприятие?

> "Наши соотечественники, которые будут
> признаны носителями русского языка,
> лицами, использующими русский язык в
> семейных ситуациях, в рамках
> культурного общения, в том случае,
> если специальная комиссия придет к
> выводу о том, что они являются
> носителями русского языка, без
> соблюдения определенных правил,
> которые касаются временного проживания
> на территории Российской Федерации,
> получения вида на жительство без
> соблюдения тех ограничений, которые
> были ранее установлены и касались
> нескольких лет, могут стать гражданами
> Российской Федерации", - говорит
> председатель комитета Госдумы РФ по
> конституционному законодательству и
> государственному строительству, член
> фракции "Единая Россия" Владимир
> Плигин.

Оригинал материала на http://www.1tv.ru/news/social/255494
Чтобы понятно было, о чём идёт речь, тема репортажа **"Знание русского упростит для иностранцев получение российского гражданства"**.

Если захотите *послушать*, как это говорится, то включите видео по ссылке с 01:12.

Comment: Nikolja, я без Вашего разрешения кросс-постинг на "Грамоте" организовал, надеюсь, не будет претензий. Очень уж понравился образчик...

Comment: Да уж. Я зависла на третьей строчке)))))

Comment: >Очень уж понравился образчик...

Мне кажется, не стоило. Ну да ладно.

Comment: :-) Почему я вообще задал этот вопрос на форум? Дело было так. У меня был напряжённый день. Устал я, дай думаю отдохну и заодно новости послушаю. 

Слушаю я этот репортаж и... что-то у меня **слова в предложение не складываются**. :-) Вот я и решил, как говорят в "Что? Где? Когда?", попросить *помощь зала*, клуба знатоков, так сказать.

.

Вообще, я думал этот вопрос удалить с форума, как неинтересный.

Comment: Не, ну а почему?

Comment: Ну честно говоря, мне показалась **интересной** сама высказанная в этом репортаже **идея**. И мне не хотелось придираться к мелочам, к тому как это было подано.

И потом, я, по возможности, стараюсь политические проблемы с языковыми не смешивать. А тут как раз тот редкий случай, когда в моем посте на форум есть что-то околополитческое.

Comment: За подробный ответ, @behemothus, отдельное спасибо! Я как раз и хотел вот так разобрать эту фразу по частям. 

.

И всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3):

Текст  в любом случае  должен  был иметь письменный вариант,  и вот непонятно какой носитель какого языка его составлял!  Стили речи могут быть разные, но содержание должно  ясно прочитываться. А этот текст явно нуждается в переводе с безграмотного на русский.  В переводе, как мне кажется, это должно выглядеть так:

"Наши соотечественники, которые специальной комиссией будут признаны носителями русского языка, то есть лицами, использующими русский язык в семейных ситуациях и в рамках культурного общения,

МОГУТ СТАТЬ ГРАЖДАНАМИ РФ без соблюдения определенных правил, которые касаются времени  проживания на территории РФ,

и ПОЛУЧИТЬ ВИД НА ЖИТЕЛЬСТВО без соблюдения ограничений по времени  в количестве нескольких лет, которые ранее были установлены".

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.Часть текста, связанного с комиссией, лучше выделить и поставить на первое место, так как не сами же носители  языка будут определять себя таковыми.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Интересно, что в других источниках неудачный фрагмент  текста был изменен на следующее: «без соблюдения определенных правил, касающихся временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации, получения вида на жительство, без соблюдения других ранее установленных ограничений».

С учетом этого, «переведенный»   вариант можно представить в следующем виде:

"Наши соотечественники, которые специальной комиссией будут признаны носителями русского языка, то есть лицами, использующими русский язык в семейных ситуациях и в рамках культурного общения, МОГУТ СТАТЬ ГРАЖДАНАМИ РФ без соблюдения определенных правил, касающихся временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации и получения вида на жительство, без соблюдения других ранее установленных ограничений».

Comment: София: <<и ПОЛУЧИТЬ ВИД НА ЖИТЕЛЬСТВО>>

Зачем человеку вид на жительство, если ему сразу дают полноценное **гражданство**?! Вид на жительство, насколько знаю, ещё не даёт избирательного права.
Смысл после *если* в *том*, что гражданство дадут в обход ранее существовавших условий: 

то *"...без соблюдения определенных правил, которые касаются*
 
*— временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации*, 

*— получения вида на жительство*,

то есть *— без соблюдения тех ограничений, которые были ранее установлены и касались нескольких лет"* (временного проживания или по виду на ПМЖ).

Comment: А так правильно? "МОГУТ СТАТЬ ГРАЖДАНАМИ РФ без соблюдения определенных правил, которые касаются временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации и получения вида на жительство без соблюдения тех ограничений, которые были ранее установлены и касались нескольких лет". Только смысл все равное не очень ясен и слова "касаются - касались" повторяются. А вы можете эту часть подредактировать?

Comment: Я только указал на очевидную нелогичность Вашего варианта: *могут стать* и *получить ВнЖ*. У меня нет цели и компетенции редактировать исходный текст (разговорного формата, с повторами и т. п., к тому же с последующим письменным изложением другим лицом) до некоторого нормативного по праву и грамматике. Ясно из самого текста и сопутствующей в Сети информации, что процесс получения гражданства при указанном новом обстоятельстве (либерализация — знание языка; помимо места рождения, родства и пр.) теперь ускоряется до месяцев (3-4?) по сравнению с годами (цензом оседлости) в прежних процедурах.

Answer (score 2):

Мое мнение - фраза настолько длинная и запутанная, что понимать её просто не обязательно.
Главное знать априри, что хотел сказать г-н Плигин. А что он хотел сказать, вытекает из общих соображений.

Я потерял желание искать какую-то грамматику примерно на середине.

{Наши соотечественники, которые будут признаны носителями русского языка, лицами, использующими русский язык в семейных ситуациях, в рамках культурного общения,}

Ладно, допустим это подлежащее.

{в том случае, если специальная комиссия придет к выводу о том, что они являются носителями русского языка,}

Тоже ладно, обстоятельство.

Но дальше...
{без соблюдения определенных правил, которые касаются временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации, получения вида на жительство без соблюдения тех ограничений, которые были ранее установлены и касались нескольких лет,}

А это как? *"Носителями русского языка без соблюдения определенных правил"*?
Ну ладно, там запятая все-таки...
Но тогда:

без соблюдения определенных правил,   
(--- которые касаются 
((------- временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации, 
((------- **получения вида на жительство без соблюдения тех ограничений**,  
(((---------- которые...

Во-первых, что такое "соблюдение ограничений"? "Получение без соблюдения" или "вид без соблюдения"?  Ну, допустим, первое, "Получение без соблюдения".

Во-вторых и в-главных:  *"**без соблюдения определенных правил**, которые касаются получения вида на жительство **без соблюдения тех ограничений**"*.

...*без соблюдения правил, которые касаются получения [вида на жительство]... без соблюдения ограничений*...

Кто-нибудь может это понять? Я  - нет.  
Или это имелся в виду таки "вид на жительство без соблюдения ограничений"?

(-------------------- 
Антивандальная копия комментария.

> Два замечания к тексту : после слова жительство следует поставить запятую, а перед словом получения - предлог без.

Лучше не стало. Все равно получается:

(--могут стать ***гражданами Российской Федерации

...

без соблюдения определенных правил***, которые касаются временного проживания на территории Российской Федерации, {без} получения вида на жительство {,} без соблюдения тех ограничений, которые были ранее установлены и касались нескольких лет,

Но это глупость уже логическая.

Answer (score 1):

Странная  идея - усваивать  язык  ради  комиссии - легче  на  лапу  дать.  А  если  комиссия  будет  состоять  из  таких  знатоков  русского  языка  вроде  авторов  обсуждаемого  текста ?! А  как  будет  проверяться  использование  языка  в  семейных  ситуациях - тут  ведь  без  жучка  не  получится ?  Или  комиссию  домашним  обедом  кормить  придётся ?

Answer (score 1):

По моему мнению, Nikolja назвал предложением речеподражательный сигнал, который издал г-н  Плигин - председатель одного из комитетов Государственной Думы Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации.

Answer (score 0):

Всяко АДЪ. Фразу понять нереально. А говорит, надо думать, о том, чтоб русскоговорящих ренационализировать без испытательного срока.